# Local database changes not saved after SubmitChanges()

Tags: sql, database, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I'm using local database to store my data. I have file `*.sdf` which I load from `Isolated Storage`, because I want my application to work also in offline mode, so if user doesn't want, he doesn't have to update data.

This is how my `DataContext` look like:

```
public class TablesDataContext : DataContext
{
    // Specify the connection string as a static, used in main page and app.xaml.
    public static string DBConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:/MyDatabase.sdf";

    // Pass the connection string to the base class.
    public TablesDataContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    { }

    // Specify a single table for the items.
    public Table<CustomerItem> CustomersTable;
    public Table<ProductItem> ProductsTable;
}
```

Here in my `App.xaml.cs` if needed I create my database:

```
// Create the database if it does not exist.
using (TablesDataContext db = new TablesDataContext(TablesDataContext.DBConnectionString))
{
    if (db.DatabaseExists() == false)
    {
        //Create the database
        db.CreateDatabase();
    }
}
dataContext = new UserDataContext();
```

And my `SettingsPage` in which I update needed information:

```
public partial class SettingsPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    // Data context for the local database
    private TablesDataContext tablesDB;

    // Define an observable collection property that controls can bind to.
    private ObservableCollection<CustomerItem> _customersTable;
    public ObservableCollection<CustomerItem> CustomersTable
    {
        get
        {
            return _customersTable;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_customersTable != value)
            {
                _customersTable = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CustomersTable");
            }
        }
    }

    // Define an observable collection property that controls can bind to.
    private ObservableCollection<ProductItem> _productTable;
    public ObservableCollection<ProductItem> ProductTable
    {
        get
        {
            return _productTable;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_productTable != value)
            {
                _productTable = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductTable");
            }
        }
    }

    public void addingCustomersToDatabase(List<CustomerJSON> customersList)
    {

        // Define the query to gather all of the to-do items.
        var customersTablesInDB = from CustomerItem todo in tablesDB.CustomersTable
                                  select todo;

        // Execute the query and place the results into a collection.
        CustomersTable = new ObservableCollection<CustomerItem>(customersTablesInDB);

        tablesDB.CustomersTable.DeleteAllOnSubmit(CustomersTable);
        tablesDB.SubmitChanges();

        foreach (CustomerJSON customer in customersList)
        {
            // Create a new to-do item based on the text box.
            CustomerItem newCustomer = new CustomerItem
            {
                // Filling customer data from JSON object
            };

            // Add a to-do item to the observable collection.
            CustomersTable.Add(newCustomer);

            // Add a to-do item to the local database.
            tablesDB.CustomersTable.InsertOnSubmit(newCustomer);
            tablesDB.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }

    public void addingProductsToDatabase(List<ProductJSON> ProductsList)
    {
           // Same things as in previouse method but with products objects
    }

    private void Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        addingCustomersToDatabase(customersList);
        addingProductsToDatabase(productsList);
    }
}
```

After updating information I'm sure that data is up-to-date, but only until I close my application. If I reopen application, it still has old data. If I understand correctly shouldn't it be saved already in my `*.sdf` file? Btw, I'm using Linq.

### EDIT:

I managed to check it and I found out that right after that JSON parsing, the database is updated (*.sdf file is filled with new data), but when I close and open application again (not build, just reopen on emulator), it again has old data.

Comment: Do you mean data modified by user? Because I don't see you saving user changes back to DB.

Comment: @AlaaMasoud No, I mean dowloading new data in JSON and then put it to database, which I do in `addingCustomersToDatabase()` method. At the end of this, I also call `SubmitChanges()` which - I assume - should save those changes, right?

Comment: Yes it should. Try retrieve the customer table from the local db right after your foreach loop and see if it has the updated data so you can isolate the problem source.

Comment: @AlaaMasoud I tried doing this by WP PowerTools, but I can't do it while my application is running, because it says that other process uses this database file.

Comment: I meant just add code after the foreach loop and query the customers table to verify updated data is there. Just add the first line your addingCustomersToDatabase() method and inspect that.

Comment: Ok I managed to check it and I found out that right after that JSON parsing, the database is updated (*.sdf file is filled with new data), but when I close and open application again (not build, just reopen on emulator), it again has old data. No idea what could be wrong.

Comment: Is this the only page that modify that particular table?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

1. Verify if the JSON data is updated
2. Try using the "AddObject" instead of "InsertOnSubmit" as below

   tablesDB.CustomersTable.AddObject(newCustomer);